# Find the longest word of a column within a text table in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, max

I have a text table defined as a list of a list of strings:

```
type Field = String
type Row   = [Field]
type Table = [Row]
```

I want to create a function that can find the width of the longest word per column, like this:

```
columnWidths :: Table -> [Int]
```

So if someone inputs a text table like this:

```
["asd", "ffdd"," 12345"]
["dd ss aa","123", "1dssd"]
```

It should give back the widths:
`[8,4,5]`

I tried some things includings maps, maximum length and transpose but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did this:

1. Find length of each text item in the table with `map length`, but I mapped that over the entire table, so `map (map length)`
2. I transposed it so that I could find the maximum in each column
3. Map that over the entire table:

---

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> let table = [["asd","ffdd","12345"],["dd ss aa","123","1dssd"]]
Prelude Data.List> let lengths = map (map length) table
Prelude Data.List> map maximum $ transpose lengths
[8,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variant of Arnon's answer, we can also transpose first and map later:

```
> map maximum . map (map length) . transpose $ table
[8,4,5]
```

We can further simplify the code above by exploiting the functor law for `map`, which states that `map f . map g = map (f . g)`:

```
> map (maximum . map length) . transpose $ table
[8,4,5]
```

Comment: Thanks @chi. I was trying to keep it simple to show the logical steps.